# How to run a console App as a new process from Asp.Net core mvc App?

Tags: asp.net-core, process, console-application

I am generating RDLC reports in my asp.net core project using AspNetCore.Reporting library. The library has cache issues and throws an exception. Thats why i want to move report generation logic to console app and run this console app as a new process from asp.net core application.

Answer (score 0):

You can run an executable from the ASP.NET Core app using the `Process.Start` method. But that is not a recommended method in this. I recommend moving the report generation logic to Azure Function or Azure App Service Web Job - which trigger based on Queue. Or use services like Hangfire - which you can also use if you're not using Azure or any other cloud platform.

Comment: Can you please help with some sample code. I am stuck with this for last two weeks. Found out that the library has cache issues and needed some work around to generate report.

Comment: Please find the following links - How to create a queue trigger function - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=csharp&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5002040

Getting started with Azure Queue - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues?tabs=dotnet&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5002040